# Warning: flock(): "Illegal operation argument" with LOCK_NB

Tags: php, flock

What am I doing wrong when I try to read data from file using flock to check if the the file lock is released to read?

I got Warning: flock(): "Illegal operation argument"

```
function SafeReadContent($file, $t = 500, $limit = 1000){
  $fp = fopen($file, "r");
  flock($fp, LOCK_NB); // This line can be removed. It for test only.
  while ( ! flock($fp, LOCK_NB) ) {
    echo "Read data performed. ";
    $str = file_get_contents($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
    usleep($t); // read/write 128kb ~ < 0.5ms
    $s++;
    if ($s==$limit) // force break
      break;
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use LOCK_NB alone. LOCK_NB must be used together with an operation. e.g.

```
if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {..
```

Comment: the second question is about using LOCK_EX and Barmar, 472k proclaims that the read proces from second script will wait (without calling the while loop used in this example... At least this is how I understand his words.